# Create and read MultipleStringValue Registry Key

Tags: c#, key, registry

I'm working on a C# project and I want to create a registry key that will be of the type MultipleStringValue.

I create it like this:

```
key.SetValue("MultipleStringValue", new string[] {"One", "Two"})
```

but the problem is that I have no clue how to read it's values afterwards.

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegistryKey class has instance method `GetValue` [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdf576x1(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdf576x1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . Have you tried to use it?

```
String[] multiStringValue = (String[])key.GetValue("MultipleStringValue");
```

Just for the future as an advice:

In OOP world(and even in any structured world) components are usually designed to implement closely related tasks (except in some specific cases) something which could be written could be read back with the same component or at least with component in the same module(namespace). If you ever encounter yourself in similar situation then use standard reference information (for C# and .NET http://msdn.microsoft.com/library).

For example just look at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey_methods(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and find a function for key deletion. Not so difficult?
Don't turn back to your own capabilities and resources. And good luck.